# ksmbd on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ubuntu, kernel-modules, samba

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 desktop, and I heard about the new `ksmbd` kernel module.
I've upgraded the system from version 21.10.

As of right now I have `samba` server and I want to migrate to the new `ksmbd`. I tried to install `ksmbd-tools` and it removed the `samba` package and made the shared folder to disappear from my Mac network view. The shared directory was set via the gnome's GUI (and not via `smb.conf`).

So how can I migrate to the new `ksmbd`?

Answer (score 0):

I just dropped by asking myself the same question and found out, it is as simple as mv/cp smb.conf to the new location `cp /etc/samba/smb.conf /etc/ksmbd/smb.conf`.
Eventually you need to `mkdir /etc/ksmbd` before and re-add your user to the /etc/ksmbd/ksmbdpwd.db by typing in `ksmbd.adduser -a <username>`

Best regards
FK

Comment: how do you know that `ksmbd` is the one doing the work and not `samba`? did you do what I did? did you remove `samba`? did you installed `ksmbd-tools`?

Comment: First you can see the ksmbd processes in your ps aux output that are the worker threads. Second, yes I installed ksmbd-tools which conflict with samba package, so you can just have the one or the other installed.

Comment: another thing, I don't use `/etc/samba/smb.conf`, I'm using the Ubuntu's GUI way, and there is another file that saves the effect (I knew but I don't remember wich). I think it complicates things.

Comment: It can be found in directory `/var/lib/samba/usershares`